# Where is fontspec.cfg?

Tags: fontspec, file-lookup

I'd like to write `\let\newfontinstance=\newfontfamily` in fontspec.cfg, but I cannot find that.

May I please know where I can find it?

Thank you!

Comment: @tim: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to mark your code as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 5):

You should copy the one that already exists in your texmf tree and put it wherever you need it. This is true for all LaTeX .cfg files. Either put it in the same directory as your document (if you only want the cfg file for that document) or put it in your *local* texmf tree so that it overrides the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out on the command line.

```
kpsewhich fontspec.cfg
```

This should give you the full path to this file.

Comment: Ok; the pathway appears to be /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg ....

Comment: but it seems hidden ...

Comment: 2010/texmf-var ... tia! once i get in there i add \let\newfontinstance=\newfontfamily ... that is to say, i paste it within the file?

Comment: @tim no, do not edit files in texmf-dist. See my answer above/below.